How to Track React Native App Installations Using Facebook Conversion API?
I’m working on a React Native app and want to track app installations using Facebook’s Conversion API. I’ve set up Facebook’s SDK in my app, but I’m having trouble integrating the Conversion API.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Integrated Facebook SDK for React Native.
Configured Facebook app events. Events can be seen on the Events Manager dashboard.
Consulted the Facebook documentation on Conversion API.

I’ve found that the Conversion API is mainly designed for server-side tracking. My questions are:

How can I send installation events from a React Native app to the Facebook Conversion API?
Are there any specific libraries or tools I should use to facilitate this integration?
Should I send these events directly from the app, or is it better to send them through a server?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

I really appreciate any help you can provide.
